# How to constrain a Dictionary's Value to a protocol

Tags: swift

I want a define a `typealias` for a Dictionary, who's key can only be of type `String` and value can only be of type that conform to the `Encodable` protocol. The reason for this is so that I can use `JSONEncoder` and encode the values later on.

I have tried:

`typealias APIParams = [String: T where Value: Encodable]` but it throws an error at me.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to encode a `APIParams` later on, you should do:

```
typealias APIParams<T: Encodable> = [String: T]
```

Type aliases can be generic! You would now be able to say e.g. `APIParams<Int>`, `APIParams<String>`, or `APIParams<YourCodableStruct>`

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried:
>
> ```
> typealias APIParams = [String: T where Value: Encodable]
> ```
>
> but it throws
> an error at me.

Closest to the way you were writing it (with a where clause) would be

```
typealias APIParams<T> = [String: T] where T: Encodable
```